# How do I show the file path on a map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Can anyone tell me how to show the file path of a map when I'm composing my final map figure. Kinda of like in excel in the headers and footers options where you can show the file path of the excel table. I am using QGIS 2.4

Comment: What software are you using (ArcGIS, QGIS?)?

Comment: Have a look here: it's almost the same question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80573/how-to-add-the-current-document-path-on-print-composer