# QGIS: startup.py missing

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to set QGIS 2.8.1 (Linux Mint 17.2) to add the filename/path to layouts.

I am using this post as a guide [How to add the current project path in Print Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80573/how-to-add-the-current-document-path-on-print-composer)
However, I haven't got startup.py - I ran searchmonkey on my entire hard disk.  The PyQGIS cookbook says "...if it's exists" but no reference to how to create it.

I tried creating a file of that name & pasting the code into it but QGIS wouldn't start, with Python-related complaints.  I'm assuming the file should have a header & instructions, like an HTML document does?  I can't seem to find this. I've looked in the QGIS settings to try & find it, with no success. BTW, I'm completely new to Python.

Comment: You might need to add the contents of what you put into your startup.py file.  This file is just a Python script, so it may not need a 'header' or instructions like an HTML document.  Your Python-related complaints would also help.

Comment: I paste this into a newly-created startup.py placed in /home/jonathan/.qgis2/python:

from qgis.core import QgsProject

@qgsfunction(0, "Python")
def projectpath(values, feature, parent):
    return QgsProject.instance.fileName()

Comment: Couldn't load qgis.user.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/user.py", line 30, in 
    execfile(startuppy, locals(), globals())
  File "/home/jonathan/.qgis2//python/startup.py", line 3, in 
    @qgsfunction(0, "Python")
NameError: name 'qgsfunction' is not defined


Python version:
2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

Comment: its not finding the qgsfunction decorator. try adding `from qgis.utils import qgsfunction` (see [this blog post](http://nathanw.net/2012/11/10/user-defined-expression-functions-for-qgis/) by NathanW)

Comment: Starts up OK now. Just need to digest that post of Nathan's - I had looked at it, but somewhat blankly.  Need to get my head round Python a bit.