# QGIS 2.18 Add partial file path to composer

Tags: qgis

[How to add the current project path in Print Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80573) doesn't quite do what I am hoping for as it gives the whole filepath (which the client doesn't need/want to see) - is there any way of just getting the last few folders?

At the  moment, using
`[%concat ( @project_path,  @project_title )%]` I get this:

> /media/jonathan/3C5VCG82K32FDB/Data/GIS/Projects/0020_Client/0019_Mynameforclientproject/Projects/QGISProjectfilename.qgs

when I just want

> /0020_Client/0019_Mynameforclientproject/Projects/QGISProjectfilename.qgs

Is this possible?

Comment: I used the hyperlink markup widget & it made the "1" as a link

Comment: I did it a much easier way by just including the link which expands to the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[% @project_path %]** is what you need to start with. Not sure why you use @project_title too.

You can use all the String functions to adjust the path to what you need. For example **left, right, length, strpos and substr**.

Depends what exactly you want. Let's say your folder structure always contains "/Data/GIS/Projects" which is the end of part you want to cut off. In that case this expression will give you only what follows after:

```
 [% right(@project_path,length(@project_path)-(strpos(@project_path,'/Data/GIS/Projects')+length('/Data/GIS/Projects')-1)) %]
```

Comment: Good to know that all the string functions can be applied to this. I jsut constructed it in the expression editor when I added the @project_title - it still gives path & filename only once though.

Comment: ...@project_title is project title, it has nothing to do with file name. You can set project title under "Project/Project Properties...". By default it is empty string. If you are after file name it is  @project_filename.